# rails deploy success but Elastic Beanstalk returns 522

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my rails5 app to elastic beanstalk container and `/log/puma.rb` saids `CMD-AppDeploy succeeded`.
I checked that schema migration and gem installation are all completed by seeing the log.

However, when I open the page by `eb open` command, it returns 522 status. How should I do to further investigation in this case?

Comment: what does `eb printenv SECRET_KEY_BASE` return?

Comment: thank you @AnthonyL, I've totally forgotten to set SECRET_KEY_BASE. I'll try and update question later

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference - this can happen if the SECRET_KEY_BASE environment variable is unset.  To set this environment variable on elastic beanstalk, you can:

`$ rake secret`

`$ eb setenv SECRET_KEY_BASE=your-secret-key-generated-above`

Comment: Bummer - are your puma logs not giving any additional information?